# CSS StyleSheet added in Scene Builder not found

Tags: java, css, netbeans, javafx-2, scenebuilder

I am getting an error in Netbeans While applying CSS style-sheet to JavaFX application through Scene Builder.

**Error message in Netbeans is:**

> null/FXMLDocument.css Sep 17, 2014 12:44:43 AM
>   com.sun.javafx.css.StyleManager loadStylesheetUnPrivileged
>
> WARNING: Resource "FXMLDocument.css" not found.

All I did is to add the css file located in the same source folder as the `FXMLDocument.fxml` file is.

[image: This is how I am applying CSS in Scene Builder to Main AnchorPane]

**Beginning of FXML looks like this:**

```xml
<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" fx:id="mainWindowPane" focusTraversable="true" stylesheets="@FXMLDocument.css" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="a.b.c.d.ui.FXMLDocumentController">
```

Any idea why is this happening, what exactly am I missing here and any suggestions to resolve this.

**Update:**

**This is the start method:**

```
@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

    try {
        setUserAgentStylesheet(STYLESHEET_MODENA);
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        Parent root = (Parent) loader.load(getClass().getResourceAsStream("ui/ParentWindow.fxml"));
        final ParentWindowController controller = (ParentWindowController) loader.getController();

        stage.addEventHandler(WindowEvent.WINDOW_SHOWN, controller::handleWindowShownEvent);
        stage.addEventHandler(WindowEvent.WINDOW_SHOWING, controller::handleWindowShowingEvent);
        stage.addEventHandler(WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSE_REQUEST, controller::handleWindowClosingRequestedEvent);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setResizable(false);
        stage.toFront();
        stage.setTitle("Sample Code");
        stage.getIcons().add(new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("resources/images/Logo.jpg")));
        stage.show();
    } catch (IOException iOException) {
        iOException.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Is this because of the `FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();` object that JavaFX is not able to resolve the absolute path to css in FXML and then `null/FXMLDocument.css`

Adding below lines in start method works fine though.

```
scene.getStylesheets().setAll(
getClass().getResource("ui/FXMLDocument.css").toExternalForm()
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Im looking into one of mayne implementation.And i use package specific to css 
and point to it via `..\css\backgroundc.css`

Notice ..\ which points to this location

If you have css  in the same package as a fxml just add `..\FXMLDocument.css` That shoud fix your problem

If you decide it to initialize it via code you can use:
for instance initialization of Scene with custom CSS Design

```
 scene.getStylesheets().setAll(
                    getClass().getResource(CSS_LOCATION).toExternalForm()
            );
```

As for CSS_LOCATION  it might be for example:

```
/myapp/ui/css/style.css
```

Or just set some of the style with string for instance

```
node.setStyle("-fx-background-color:RED;");
```

^^btw This doesnt limit you to declare only one style/within string ; is delimiter and you can add more.As in normal css file.

Comment: well I really tried to amke it work but no luck so far. So just decided to go with `scene.getStylesheets().setAll(getClass().getResource(CSS_LOCATION).toExternalForm());`

Which works fine. Thanks

But this is still not the solution that I was looking for.

Comment: @Indigo Have you tryed to click on + next to /FXMLDocument.css and navigate to your css thru system directories?All the way  c:\Users\username\documents\NetBeansProjects... etc ? It will change pointing path  based on package structure and shoud work.

Comment: Actually that's how I added the CSS in Scene Builder. From the null in error message it looks like JavaFX is not able to get the absolute path to the CSS. I will update the question with some more part of the code to get an idea.

Comment: FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(); has no effect on this afaik.This is correct initialization.And also works in my case this way.

Comment: well this is really strange then, I will play around with this more and see if can make it work. Just curious to know whats exactly is wrong there.